# How to add selections together using using switch statement in C?

Tags: c, switch-statement

I have wrote out most of my program but I must be missing something in it. I wrote out a menu and list the items to choose and wrote out a switch statement to run the choices. How do I get it to add the choices together to give a total amount? Right now it asks for the two choices(will change this to 3 later)and only runs the amount for the first choice after the two choices are entered. Not sure what is wrong.

```
printf("1. Hamburger        $%.2lf \n", Hamburger_Price);
printf("2. Cheeseburger     $%.2lf \n", Cheeseburger_Price);
printf("3. Chicken Sandwich $%.2lf \n", Chicken_Sandwich_Price);
printf("4. Fries            $%.2lf \n", Fries_Price);
printf("5. Onion Rings      $%.2lf \n", Onion_Rings_Price);
printf("6. Soda             $%.2lf \n", Soda_Price);
printf("7. Milkshake        $%.2lf \n", Milkshake_Price);
printf("8. Exit\n\n");

printf("Please make a selection: ");
scanf("%i", &selection);


switch(selection)
{
case 1:
totalprice += Hamburger_Price;
break;

case 2:
totalprice += Cheeseburger_Price;
break;

case 3:
totalprice += Chicken_Sandwich_Price;
break;

case 4:
totalprice += Fries_Price;
break;

case 5:
totalprice += Onion_Rings_Price;
break;

case 6:
totalprice += Soda_Price;
break;

case 7:
totalprice += Milkshake_Price;
break;

case 8:
printf("Thank you for your order. \n");
break;

default:
printf("Sorry we dont have that. \n");
}

printf("Please make another selection: ");
scanf("%i", &selection);


printf("Your total comes to $%.2lf \n\n", totalprice);
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch statement is not a loop statement, it is done only once. In order to enter into the switch statement multiple times you can put it in a loop statement. And do not forget to add an exit condition. For example let's say that the end condition will be to introduce the value 8:

```
printf("Please make a selection: ");
scanf("%i", &selection);

while(selection != 8)
{
    switch(selection)
    {
    /*your code*/
    }
    printf("Please make another selection: ");
    scanf("%i", &selection)
}
/*I think there is no need for the "case 8:" in your code*/
printf("Thank you for your order. \n");
```

Comment: Sabin, thank you so much. that helped and made the program run great. didn't know about the while statement but feel good at least the rest seemed good. Thanks again